# All Reboots Prompts Advanced Boot Options

Tags: boot, windows-server-2012

I have a Windows 2012 Server (Not R2) and every time it reboots, regardless of cause (for example power outage, rebooting from the server, updates, etc all produce the same problem) it goes to the advanced boot options menu and doesn't continue until I select boot normally.

I've gone into Startup and Recovery and set to automatically restart with and without displaying operating systems list, and recovery options.

I've gone into msconfig (system config) and set normal startup.

I've used the command prompt with bcdedit and the commands:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} displaybootmenu no
bcdedit /set {current} bootmenupolicy Standard
```

Nothing seems to change the results. Every single time I reboot for any reason, I'm met with the same screen shown below and I have to manually select Start Windows Normally.
[image]
I want the Windows server to automatically boot to the desktop when I hit restart without human intervention. Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Try: (1) In *System Properties > Advanced tab*, under "Startup and Recovery", set or unset the option of "Time to display list of operating systems". (2) If you boot in Safe Mode then shutdown, does this happen?

Comment: @harrymc No change